# Input voltage drop

Tags: voltage-regulator, load

I have a circuit, the characteristic of the load is unknown, most probably resistance and capacitance, the input for the circuit is %v and frequency is varying from 10 Hz to 30 MHz. once the input frequency crosses 200 KHz the input voltage gradually reduces. Can anyone explain is it because of the conductance in the load?

Comment: Add the schematic in question

Comment: Your question is very limited in information about the circuit. You have to take into consideration, that a circuit can be fairly complex with hundreds of components or building blocks. So it may be very useful to have a circuit diagram like @MITURAJ suggests, even if it consists only of black boxes wired to each other. On top of that it is very useful to know something about the purpose of the circuit. This allows people here to throw in their knowledge about similar circuitry. (Hint: use the circuit tool to enter a basic schematic for us)

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** some series R and shunt RC load.

1) Capacitors are insulators with a dielectric constant,k much greater than air k=1 and they store (absorb) and release energy. So technically they do not conduct electricity but rather absorb charges or release them.

Cap's are measured in Farads with prefix multipliers such as picofarads [pF]

A pF is about the value between two hands held apart. Whereas your fingertip alone may be 100pF relative to the rest of your body, but if moist and squeezed to the measurement electrode might exceed  1 nF from the contact pressure.

2) Resistors are conductors and absorb power in watts. Resistance is measured in Ohms

The break frequency (output drops -3dB) for a simple 1st order ( 1 cap) filter is defined as 2pi*f = ω = 1/RC

So to answer your question, the attenuation is due to the ratio of series conduction loss  and load absorption  or the impedance ratios.